# Command "make:notification" is not defined. | Lumen 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, lumen

In the process of developing push notification application in Lumen, it is needed to run `php artisan` command to make notifications. When I run `php artisan` `make:notification` (`php artisan make:notification`)command is not available. I get the following error.

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
```

`Command "make:notification" is not defined`.

```
 Did you mean one of these?
      make:migration
      make:seeder
```

Please help me to  solve this issue. 
thanks

Comment: I am not sure if there is that function for Lumen...Lumen is an API framework. In Laravel that function exists since version 5.3 I think.

Comment: I'm using version 5.5

Comment: Laravel or Lumen???

Comment: It's lumen. When I try to follow tutorial, it was in Laravel. I think it's okay to user laravel code in Lumen. Please explain

Comment: It is not OK to use Laravel code in Lumen....half of things does not work in Lumen! Lumen is a stripped off version of Laravel meant to be used only for API. That means no browser things and blade and stuff.

Comment: Thanks Lewis (Y). I am new to this framework. Do you have an idea on how to achieve my task ?

Comment: I have made an answer on that question below... check that link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Command `php artisan make:notification NameOfNotification` does not exist in Lumen.

You would have to import that package.

Source: https://stevethomas.com.au/php/using-laravel-notifications-in-lumen.html

---

The first step is requiring the illuminate/notifications package:

```
composer require illuminate/notifications
```

Maybe you will `require illuminate/support`, i'm not 100% if this is a required dependency for notifications. If you get errors this might be why.

Next, register the service provider in bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register(\Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class);

// optional: register the Facade
$app->withFacades(true, [
    'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification' => 'Notification',
]);
```

Add the Notifiable trait to whichever models you like, User would be an obvious one:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

Write notifications the normal way:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Spaceship;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class SpaceshipHasLaunched extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /** @var Spaceship */
    public $spaceship;

    /**
     * @param Spaceship $spaceship
     */
    public function __construct(Spaceship $spaceship)
    {
        $this->spaceship = $spaceship;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param mixed $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Spacheship has launched!')
            ->markdown('mail.spaceship', [
                'spaceship' => $this->spaceship
            ]);
    }
}
```

Send notifications from your app the normal way:

```
$user->notify(new Notifications\SpaceshipHasLaunched($spaceship));
```

Comment: hahaa pretty much the same article pasted :D . anyway I upvoted :)

Comment: Those are the rules of stack overflow. When you make an answer you should provide the code or explain it so even if the link is broken you can solve the problem by reading only the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help you.